# Failure to launch - shells and incomplete commands - in VScode

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, zsh, zshrc, luxonis

I seem to be having an interesting problem on occasion when vscode tries to launch a shell, especially during debugging.

For example, I'm trying to debug a Python program that uses an Anaconda venv. Everything is set up correctly from the interpreter's POV and all that. Indeed, if I run the commands that vscode is trying to evaluate in the shell 'by hand' everything works, debuggery-wise.

But - the first time I try, I get a weird mess in the terminal window when I launch the program to debug.

Output from the terminal window is seen below -

```
source /Users/flip/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate
 ~/G/depthai> da3/bin/activate
zsh: no such file or directory: da3/bin/activate
 127  ~/G/depthai> nconda activate depthai
zsh: command not found: nconda
```

What seems to be happening is that `vscode` is trying to `source /Users/flip/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate` and a bunch of characters aren't making it to to the shell itself (the first part of the string, `/Users/flip/opt/anacon` to be specific)

Then, as you can see it's trying to run `conda activate depthai` and, this time, an `n` is being prepended to the command. Very weird, suspicious, and all that.

This seems to happen w/ `bash` and `zsh` on both macOS and on my Linux boxes. It *feels* like there's something weird / messy in whichever `rc` files are getting executed. I've been using a similar configuration of `.profile` and friends for *literally* decades and, at some point, maybe I added something that is doing naughty IO?

Any thoughts out there?

Comment: Why don't you turn on `set -x` just for debugging? While this will create a lot of output, you will at least find the file and the line in it which causes the trouble.

Comment: Yea - a good point but the output from the `set -x` exacerbates the problem - but I could do something like that and run outside vscode and sniff `stderr|out`. I recall doing that in the past with no insight though.

Comment: At the very least, you see from the trace the line and the file where the problem occurs. Also, it would help if you tell us, whether the shell opened from within visual studio, is a login-shell or a non-login shell.

Answer (score 2):

What ultimately solved it for me was [overriding the shell used for automation tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles#_configuring-the-taskdebug-profile) (like debugging) to the barebones `/bin/sh` which should load as fast as possible. You can do so by adding the following to your VSCode's `settings.json`:

```
  "terminal.integrated.automationProfile.linux": {
    "path": "/bin/sh"
  },
  "terminal.integrated.automationProfile.osx": {
    "path": "/bin/sh"
  }
```

If falling back to `/bin/sh` isn't an option for some reason, you can use the same mechanism to keep the same shell but override args/env variables allowing you to conditionally speed up initialization in your `.zprofile`/`.zshrc` scripts (e.g. skip loading of unnecessary plugins):

```
"terminal.integrated.automationProfile.osx": {
    "path": "/bin/zsh",
    "args": ["-l"],
    "env": {
      "FAST_INIT": "true"
    }
  },
```

## Background

I was having a similar issue with the node debugger where the command injection done when launching the debug session would get intermittently truncated. This truncation invariably led to the debugger being stuck waiting for extra input due to an unterminated string.

```bash
alexandre.fonseca ~/myProject                                                            17:28:54
❯ esources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.js-debug/src/bootloader.js" --inspect-publish-uid=http' 'VSCODE_INSPECTOR_OPTIONS={"inspectorIpc":"/var/folders/yz/1ddh54557hj_lxdt_55x3q
mr0000gp/T/node-cdp.54381-bc269a2e-1.sock","deferredMode":false,"waitForDebugger":"","execPath":"/Users/alexandre.fonseca/.asdf/shims/node","onlyEntrypoint":false,"autoAttac
hMode":"always","fileCallback":"/var/folders/yz/1ddh54557hj_lxdt_55x3qmr0000gp/T/node-debug-callback-84b6ad0f17eec2d2"}' /Users/alexandre.fonseca/.asdf/shims/yarn test:unit 
/Users/alexandre.fonseca/myProject/process-response.unit.ts 
>
```

Disabling my fancy ZSH prompt plugins seemed to make the issue occur less frequently.

Stumbled upon https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/38578#issuecomment-725558731 which suggests command injection is based purely on time and thus quite easy to race with complex shell initialization scripts.